# CTRL+X, CTRL+V of files across terminal sessions resorts to CTRL+C/CTRL+V behavior

Tags: terminal-services

When we cut a file and paste it in another computer through 'Terminal Session' window, after the paste operation completes, I find that the source is still there.  Is it something a Terminal Session which overrides our cut-paste behavior and presents a copy-paste instead?

Answer (score 0):

Some operating systems will not let you "cut" across file systems, you can only copy. You don't give any detail about your setup, but this is probably the case. If you need to get rid of the original file, you'll have to delete it separately.

Comment: Both the host and guest are Windows 7 Ultimate. The former is the desktop and latter is the laptop.